# How much snow for tevilah?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, mikvah-ritual-bath, water, snow

In respect to tovelling dishes in the snow, [this discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23448/can-one-tovel-dishes-in-snow?rq=1) concludes that who knows what the Shulchan Aruch holds, but the Rema allows such a practice in times of need.

But just how much snow? After all, water expands when frozen. Must one use a mikveh of 40 se'ah of water, which could be as much as 800 se'ah of snow depending on how densely packed it is, or can one use a mikveh of 40 se'ah of snow, even though that's much, much less than 40 se'ah of water? That is, once we've said that snow is mutar [b'sha'as dechak](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4121/9682), does this mean it has to contain the same amount of water as a normal mikveh, or the same volume as a normal mikveh?

Comment: I can't imagine why the air would count. It's clearly 40 seah of ice.

Comment: @DoubleAA Which is still bigger than 40 se'ah of water

Comment: @DonielF No it's not. They're both 40 se'ah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, yeah, "Which is heavier, a pound of bricks or a pound of feathers..." What I mean is that the water contained in 40 se'ah of even solid ice is less than that contained in 40 se'ah of water. So would we then still require 40 se'ah, even though it's not the same amount of water?

Comment: @DonielF Would you require less water at 4 degrees Celsius when water is most dense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44400/discussion-between-donielf-and-double-aa).